# How I can install Mate 1.10 on Ubuntu Mate 15.04?

Tags: mate

I have Ubuntu Mate 15.04 with Mate 1.8.2. I want install new Mate, 1.10. How i can get it? I've tried

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but it not work.

Comment: Did you also try running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` after that?

Comment: Yes, not helped.

Comment: install from source. https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-desktop

Answer (score 1):

Currently? There are no packages in the PPAs for Mate 1.10

[ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mate-dev/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)
[ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/vivid-mate](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mate-dev/+archive/ubuntu/vivid-mate)

So you have to compile the packages itself. You can download the source archives from [here](http://pub.mate-desktop.org/releases/1.10/) or clone the repository from [here](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-desktop).

---

Usually you need an additionally PPA for Vivid:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/vivid-mate
```

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news* **;)**

Comment: Thanks, i update mate-package. But what is next? I reboot PC, but I still have 1.8.2. Why?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer "Currently, there are no packages in the PPAs for Mate 1.10".

Comment: http://mate-desktop.org/donate/  this might help get a package out faster.